# PostgreSQL text field loads as strL

Tags: postgresql, odbc, stata

I have data stored in PostgreSQL with the data type `text`.

When I load this data into Stata it has type `strL`, even if every string in a column is only one charter long. This takes up too much memory. I would like to continue using the `text` type in PostgreSQL.

Is there a way to specify that `text` data from PostgreSQL is loaded into Stata with type `str8`?

I also want numeric data to be loaded as numeric values so `allstring` is not a good solution. I would also like to avoid specifying data type on a column by column basis.

The command I use to load data into Stata is this:

```
odbc load, exec("SELECT * FROM mytable")  <connect_options>
```

The file `profile.do` contains the following:

```
set odbcmgr unixodbc, permanently
set odbcdriver ansi, permanently
```

The file `odbci.ini` contains the following:

```
[database_name]
Debug = 0
CommLog = 0
ReadOnly = no
Driver = /usr/local/lib/psqlodbcw.so
Servername = <server>
FetchBufferSize = 99
Port = 5432
Database = postgres
```

In PosrgreSQL `mytable` looks like this:

```
postgres=# \d+ mytable
                      Table "public.mytable"
 Column | Type | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description
--------+------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 c1     | text |           | extended |              |
 c2     | text |           | extended |              |


postgres=# select * from mytable;
 c1 |  c2
----+-------
 a  | one
 b  | two
 c  | three
(3 rows)
```

In Stata `mutable` looks like this:

```
. describe

Contains data
  obs:             3                          
 vars:             2                          
 size:           500                          
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
              storage   display    value
variable name   type    format     label      variable label
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
c1              strL    %9s                   
c2              strL    %9s                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sorted by: 
     Note: Dataset has changed since last saved.
```

I am using PostgreSQL v9.6.5 and Stata v14.2.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Stata by `compress`-ing your data after you load the variables:

```
clear

input strL string
"My name is Pearly Spencer"
"I am a contributor on Stack Overflow"
"This is an example variable"
end

describe 

Contains data
  obs:             3                          
 vars:             1                          
 size:           355                          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              storage   display    value
variable name   type    format     label      variable label
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
string          strL    %9s                   
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sorted by: 
     Note: Dataset has changed since last saved.

compress, nocoalesce 

describe

Contains data
  obs:             3                          
 vars:             1                          
 size:           108                          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              storage   display    value
variable name   type    format     label      variable label
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
string          str36   %36s                  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sorted by: 
     Note: Dataset has changed since last saved.
```

The option `nocoalesce` forces Stata to choose the appropriate length for the loaded string variables.

Comment: This works, but compress is very slow on large datasets.